# In Linux (POSIX in general), how do I determine if a thread is in a syscall?

Tags: linux, multithreading, posix, system-calls

I have to know if a thread is currently executing a system call (e.g. read/write/etc.) by knowing its tid. Is there a way to do that in Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should list the state code of the thread

```
ps -p<pid> -o stat
```

The two relevant codes are:

```
D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
```

Edit:
If you want to get the exact system call programmatically, you could use `ptrace` as you have suggested and read `EAX`, you should also use the `PTRACE_SYSCALL` flag to have the process stop at the next system call entry.

Comment: Is there a way to know what is the exact system call?

Comment: No, not without instrumenting your kernel.  Note that if you want that information programmatically instead of via a command line tool, it's exposed in /proc/<pid>/status in the line beginning "State:"

Comment: You might also look into `strace(1)` utility.

Comment: I think I can make it show its EAX with ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, ...) Will this block until the syscall is done? I know it will be running on i386 or x86_64.

Comment: Syscall number is stored in EAX when making the syscall.

Comment: @HristoVenev right, that should work, you didn't tag any programming language so I assumed you wanted to do it from the command line, you may want to use `PTRACE_SYSCALL` to stop the process at the next system call.

Comment: Beware: there's an unfixable race if you try that.  The system provides no locking mechanism between the read() call in procfs and the ptrace() call.  The EAX/RAX you get back may not be the same system call you started with (it might have done a few thousand in the interrim!), and it may not correspond to a syscall at all if the call has returned.  That technique can't work reliably.  Look to something like systemtap or lttng if you want to trace long-running syscalls.

Comment: You won't be able to even attach to a `D`-state process with `ptrace` (because that would interrupt the syscall). You'll be waiting for the process to become interruptible.